# How to prevent buffering while pausing audio in MediaElementJS?

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElementJS as audio player. When I pause the player, audio still continues to buffer. This happens when the player uses flash to play the audio (FF & IE7 & 8) and I'm playing .mp3 file.

I google it and few recommended to use pause the player and load empty string to setSrc function, but it didn't work and still buffering the audio.

Here is the code I have used to stop buffering:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player-1');

    player.pause();
    player.setSrc('');
    player.load();
</script>
```

Is that correct method? What mistake I made? How can I prevent buffering when I pause the player?

Can you anyone help me fixing this issue?

Thanks,